# AWS EventBridge Rule triggering on SSM Parameter Store change not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I have a seemingly easy problem that already has cost me hours of troubleshooting without finding any solution.

What I'm trying to to is simple: Create an EventBridge Rule that triggers on an SSM Parameter Store Parameter change.

I use the default EventBus. The AWS console (when manually clicking through the options) is suggesting this event pattern which seems easy enough:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ssm"],
  "detail-type": ["Parameter Store Change"]
}
```

The problem is: It doesn't work. I tried adding, updating, deleting parameter store parameters but the rule never triggered (evident from the CloudWatch metrics)

What I already tried:

I tried creating the rule both with the GUI and CloudFormation with no observable difference in results.

I tried further specifying the event pattern to check if it required a parameter name in order to work. Still no triggers.

I tried creating parameters with different names (with or without leading /) but it made no difference.

I tried searching for any logs that EventBridge might create (no success).

I tried looking up the events that EventBridge records in the default EventBus. It doesn't seem possible to directly access the actual events to check how they look like. CloudTrail events are not the same events.

I checked the internet for people having similar problems but apparently I'm the only one.

Comment: Everything you've tried looks correct to me. You could try removing everything but the `source` specification in your event pattern to make it even less specific, to see if any SSM events at all are making it to your EventBridge bus. But it honestly sounds like system events in your account are not making it into the default event bus. You may need to open a ticket with AWS support about that.